# No audio after converting using AVS Video Converter & FreeMakeVideo Converter

Tags: windows-7, audio, video-conversion

I installed K-Lite Codec Pack some month ago in my Windows 7 Ultimate machine.  As far as I know, every thing about Media Player Classic & KMPlayer is ok.

I am trying to to convert a mkv file to mp4.
The problem is output file has no AUDIO in either AVS Video Converter & FreeMakeVideo Converter. The result for both of them are the same.

What is the problem & how can I fix it?

I tried to change all options for output audio format.
No success at all.

---

**EDIT AFTER 1 ANSWER**

Here is MediaInfo result of that mkv video :
[image: MediaInfo result]
For `ffmpeg.exe` i searched my pc.
It found it on the path below :
`C:\Program Files\KMPlayer`
And also `ffmpeg.dll` on the path belows :
`C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\ffdshow`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\ffdshow64`

I copied `ffmpeg.exe` from KMPlayer to a folder and tried those commands like below :
[image: ffmpeg.exe Result]
[image: ffmpeg.exe Result_2]
Now `output.mp4` is not playable on KMPlayer.
Any idea?

---

All of my videos have downloaded with IDM from `YouTube` web site.
Online Converters can convert those mkv videos.
But those two softwares  can't.

Comment: As a sanity check, have you tried using other video conversion software like Handbrake? No need to convert the whole file, just convert a small part of the video and see if the audio is missing in the resulting file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no audio problems, be assured you have audio in this file, and also what type of audio you have, reading sources with `ffmpeg -i file.mkv` or with `MediaInfo`software.

Then,

Try with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

To see the results and I'm assuming here you're not trying to play it on internet.

Also try with other players if it's Linux and Media Player Classic if it's Windows.

> There's a reason why I've mentioned ffmpeg.

---

UPDATE: Try ˋffmpegˋ from the **official website** and that haven't been compiled from any other sources yet.

As I've seen you're using a compiled version from KMPlayer, and you're not supossed to use that.

Some notices:

- you cannot use .h264/video and opus/audio together in a .mp4 container since it isn't compatible, it needs to be inside .mkv container. The reason why I've mentioned to convert it to aac/audio to solve this issue.
- As well avoid the mistake, if any, to download specific audio/video size format like 720p to then interrupt and continue it from another size video/audio  format like 1080p to the same container as it will break the file anyways